# Different logic if both or only one key present in object?

Tags: javascript

I have this kind of schema:

```
const schema = {
  actions: {
    ident: {
      action: (v) => v,
      path: 'some.path.key',
    },
    mul: {
      action: (v) => v * 2,
      path: 'some.other.path.key',
    },
  },
};
```

And a helper function, that takes object with keys present in schema actions, e.g:

```
const obj = {
  ident: 1,
  mul: 2,
}

const res = helper(schema, obj);

/* res */
{
  some: {
    path: {
      key: 1,
    },
    other: {
      path: {
        key: 4,
      }
    }
  },
}
```

And construct a new object with a function applied to the value.

Sometimes i need a behavior when both keys present in source object, e.g:

```
const schema2 = {
  actions: {
    ident: {
      action: (v) => v,
      path: 'some.path.key',
    },
    mul: {
      action: (v) => v * 2,
      path: 'some.other.path.key',
    },
    'mul:ident': {
      action: (v1, v2) => v1/v2,
      path: 'key',
    }
  },
};
```

In case like this, i need the result object to be:

```
const obj = {
  ident: 1,
  mul: 2,
}

const res = helper(schema, obj);

/* res */
{
  key: 2  // 2/1 == 2
}
```

How can i implement such conditional logic in a good way?

Comment: How do you know that the final action is the last one?

Comment: pair keys have more precedence, there is nothing about order of keys in the object

Comment: And what if there are two pair keys?

Comment: they will be checked first, if left and right side of ':' is present in source obj, then rule applies. if not then single keys of a pair is checked

Comment: and there will be no overlapping pairs, e.g. 'ident:mul', 'mul:mul' or 'mul:add'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd traverse your actions backwards, then delete the keys from the input, and skip the action if the keys are missing:

```
  const input = { ...obj };
  const output = {};

  // you might want to sort the keys in the desired order first (e.g. by the number of parameters)
  for(const [key, { action, path }] of Object.entries(schema.actions).reverse()) {
    const keys = key.split(".");
    // If one ov the values is missing, another action already consumed it
    if(keys.some(key => !(key in input))
       continue;
    // consume all keys into values
    const values = keys.map(key => { 
       const value = input[key];
       delete input[key];
    });
    // TODO: assign path to output correctly
    output[path] = action(...values);
 }
```